# is there a way to display only child if it exists or else only parent data

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and one is parent table and second one is child table both tables has transactions but where as some transactions will take place in parent table and some in child based on their child existence if the parent row doesn't have any child it will be the result and if the parent has the child the child table itself will be the result some times both may occur i tried but not getting the exact solution please help.....

1st table and Parent table

| id | item | amount | tax | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 20 | 2 | Y |
| 2 | 5 | 15 | 1 | N |
| 3 | 6 | 5 | 0 | N |

2nd table and child table

| id | item | p_id | amount | tax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 10 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 15 | 1 |

3rd table

| id | item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | mobile |
| 2 | heater |
| 3 | mouse |
| 4 | electronic |
| 5 | software |
| 6 | papers |

What I want is

| item | amount | tax |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mobile | 10 | 1 |
| heater | 10 | 1 |
| mouse | 15 | 1 |
| software | 15 |  |
| papers | 5 | 0 |

Comment: Why `tax` for `item='software'` in output is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT IFNULL(child.item, parent.item) AS item, 
       IFNULL(child.amount, parent.amount) AS amount,
       IFNULL(child.tax, parent.tax) AS tax
FROM parent
LEFT JOIN child ON parent.id = child.p_id
```

Comment: Sir I just added one update to the question

Comment: I tried using sub quires but it is not working please update the answer

Comment: I have just added a new reference table instead of writing direct data in to item column in all tables

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COALESCE(child.item, parent.item) item,
       COALESCE(child.amount, parent.amount) amount,
       COALESCE(child.tax, parent.tax) tax
FROM parent
LEFT JOIN child ON parent.id = child.p_id
```

Comment: Sir I made a small change in the question I have added a new reference table I tried it but not working please respond